# NotImplementedError error on Opening a file inside password protected zip file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip, python-zipfile

I need to open and read text files in encrypted zip files (password protected). I know the password used. I wrote a code in Python like this. But I got an error:

"NotImplementedError: That compression method is not supported"

I have tried the code on zip files created in WinRAR (Windows) and also by Linux archiver, and the results were the same. Even extract() and extractall() methods  couldn't extract files.

What could be wrong with this code??!

```
import zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile(file='E:\Test\a_zip_file.zip',mode='r') as zip_file:
    file_list = zip_file.namelist()
    for file in file_list:
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
            with zip_file.open(file,mode='r',pwd=bytes('1234','utf-8')) as wt:  ## b'1234' doesn't work either
                ''' above line raises the error: NotImplementedError: That compression method is not supported'''
                byte_lines = wt.readlines()
                for byte_line in byte_lines:
                    line = (byte_line.decode(encoding='utf-8')).strip('\n')
                    ''' and the rest reading text process '''
```